# Android base64 returns different results

Tags: java, android, base64

I've been reading the same kind of problem and also tried most of the solutions, but i still keep getting the the same results from the servers logs.

I'm using this code to encode it to base 64. I've tried changing the charset to UTF-8 , US-ASCII and ISO back and forth and still having the same results.

```
 String creds = "android:android";
     byte [] credentials = new byte[0];
     credentials = creds.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
     final String basicAuth = "Basic " +Base64.encodeToString(credentials,Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

This is the result from the server logs which is using perl:

"�"q���ɽ��酹�ɽ�"

Result that I've been getting from my logs are working fine. It is just from the server logs that is posting that.

Logcat result: YW5kcm9pZDphbmRyb2lk

Comment: Try different  combinations for the encoder flag. like `Base64.NO_PADDING`, `BASE64.DEFAULT` and so on

Comment: I also tried changing the encoder flag, still the same result

Comment: That is Java code, not Perl. I've added the Java tag

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Had to remove the string "Basic". Now the string is decoded properly from the server.